# Invoke the emplace function when developing contracts seems not executed?

Tags: smart-contract

I want to develop a contract and save data by using emplace function. Below is my code:

```
offer_bets_index offerbets(_self, player);

eosio::print("begin to write db\n");

auto bets_itr = offerbets.emplace(_self, [&](auto& offerbet) {
    eosio::print("new offer bet");
    uint64_t id = offerbets.available_primary_key();
    eosio::print("new available key:", id);
    offerbet.id        = id;
    offerbet.player    = player;
    offerbet.draw      = draw;
    offerbet.bet       = bet;
    offerbet.buycnt    = buycnt;
    offerbet.buylottos = buylottos;
    offerbet.buytime   = buytime;
});
eosio::print("end write", bets_itr->id);
```

Only the first `eosio::print` content show correctly, but the print content inside the lambda function and the last print content didn't show.
Seems like the emplace function didn't been executed in the action?

Anybody knows why?? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to check your node console window/log? Sometimes for me the output messages are only there and does not show anything at my cleos... not sure why...

Comment: @LeoRibeiro This problem also happen to me. I found that, if you add -j option with your cleos command, you will find the console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that, the abi file generated by eosiocpp was I expected. Check your abi file and pay attention to your @abi annotation, maybe you will fix this problem.This is my solution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can remove the "\n" in the first "print" function, i also met this problem. but not sure what the real reason is.

Comment: Not work for me, but thanks for your suggestion. I suppose the eosio::print function print the log in asynchronous thread, so that sometimes the log will lost.

Comment: @Harry Ma i also met this problem,and remove the "\n".but how output "\n"？